# Capturing 360 panorama in android

Tags: android

I want to capture 360 panoramic image through camera of android device, but the example posted in this link http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/downloads/list, is only display the panoramic image not capturing with it. But I want to capture a panoramic image in 360 degree. I have searched on web enough regarding same but always failures, can any one help me for developing the same as in 360 app of android market which is already doing the same.
Please suggest me regarding this subject and help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699069/capture-image-automatically-like-360-panorama

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

1. Capture multiple images from the camera, possibly using a sensor on the device in order to help take the images. Using a fixed exposure setting is ideal.
2. Use an image stitching algorithm to combine them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching

Comment: OK, then how to see the same image in panoramic behavior?

Comment: Can you define "Panoramic Behavior"? Scrolling in an image?

Comment: Yes, and one question also, how to check 360 degree completion of rotation of device and how to stop capturing images and also how we define when to capture at what angle? Please elaborate your answer.....