# Capture image automatically like 360 Panorama

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sensors, panoramas

I am working on the application which is similar to Panorama app.I want to capture  the image automatically when device moved from left to right like 360 panorama app works.After  few research,I came to know that [Sensor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) and thread can be useful for that and I have seen some examples of sensor [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSensor/article.html).But I couldn't understand about how to use sensor for my purpose.I also could not find any tutorial related to sensor with camera for auto capturing image.If anybody have any idea or example regarding this then plz suggest me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are talking about the event handling using accelerometer of the android , you can capture the events like here [How to detect shake event with android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271448/how-to-detect-shake-event-with-android) , and then can possibly turn on your camera and perform your events.

Also try this http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472

Update :

You need to capture the multiple images and then combine them by using specific algorithm to have the Panoram 360 view on it.

Update 2 :

The algorithm like Image stitching like this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching

Most Important Thing : No one is going to reveal their algorithm on any opensource forum (As per I know)

***Have a look at this too :*** http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4670/2010fa/projects/final/results/group_of_acc269_ty244_yc563/cs4670_final.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have already gone through your links before.Your given links are for the shaking events and Actually I could not understand how to use it for my purpose of capturing the image on device movement?Any idea?

Comment: look you need to start your camera on the specific events , these movements are the pointers for you when you need to capture the events ? If I am not in the line where you are, can you please elaborate your problem in more detail ?

Comment: :Thanks for the reply.I have already done the image stitching part using OpenCV.I have also seen your last link which is also using opencv.I have also tried to use that but my problem is how to use sensor during image capture and in the last link also I could not find that solution.

Comment: you have done the hardest part and now you are running for the easy solution , I think you should try enabling the sensor , whenever you camera starts...though I have not tried , I only have this answer :)

Comment: ohk..Thanks..I am trying to do it but not get success till now.Anyways thanks for your help

Comment: at least I deserve thumbs up :)

Comment: I have already upvoted you.But I can't accept you answer because for that you have to help me one more time :-)

Comment: Thank u very much for your great support:)

Comment: Which sensor you want to use ?

Comment: hey @krushnakant have you done panorama with sensor?

Comment: @krushnakant i am compiling opencv pano stiching project but it causes error in compiling , its humble request if you can help me to do that successfully. i have posted [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617572/compiling-opencv-library-for-imagestitching-using-androiud-ndk-in-cygwin-but-it] (question and error) on this .