# Compiling OpenCV library for image stitching using android NDK in cygwin throws error from creating libutils.so

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, cygwin

I am using OpenCV-2.4.9 sdk and [OpenCV stitching library](https://github.com/tanmengwen/android-opencv-panorama) for creating **panorama image** which is to be compiled and creating .so files to libs folder inside application

- I am using cygwin on windows to compile jni directory from project. it gives error like picture shown below:

[image: cygwin screen]

- tried in windows 7,8 (x86,x64) but it gives same error
- successfully compiled other OpenCV example libraries but this one not compiling successfully.

Does anyone know what is causing this error to be thrown?

Comment: Text errors messages please.

Comment: error: undefined reference to 'cv::exception::exception(int,std::string const&,std::... shown in image above.